# ie7-8 not rendering wrapper with image width: 100%

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

I have an issue with my homepage in IE7-8, it seems that the slider wrapper with the background image, for some reason is not being rendered, forcing the inner div to not be centered and look all messed up.

Take a look [here](http://cmf.sd1dev2.co.uk), it all works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox. But not IE! How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You are using HTML5 tags, those are not supported in older browsers.

Comment: I am using html tags on other parts of the page though, they are working because I have modernizer. I don't think it's a HTML5 thing?

Comment: It most likely is an HTML5 thing. Never trust IE.

Comment: @rowefx: Somewhere in your CSS you have specified `body { width: 90% }`, and this is only applied in IE 8 and earlier.

Comment: Ok seems like it is a html5 thing, though I DO have modernizer loaded, why is IE being a ****?

Comment: @rowefx: Web designs easily become complex, so that the smallest browser difference have a big impact. Even with modernizr, browsers still behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

Still HTML5/CSS3 is not supported for IE so please tryout with other tag like div or any block tags

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, the [**Html5shiv**](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) script allows you to use HTML5 tags on older browsers.

Comment: I'm using Modernizer - " As of Modernizr 1.5, this script is identical to what is used in the popular html5shim/html5shiv library. Both also enable printability of HTML5 elements in IE6-8, though you might want to try out the performance hit if you have over 100kb of css."